# React Rodal not fitting the text inside the modal window

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, less

I have the following simple project on `StackBlitz`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rodal-issue

with this style:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rodal-issue?file=src%2FModalWindow%2FModalWindow.less

```
.modalWindow {
  z-index: 1050 !important;
  .rodal-mask {
    background-color: rgba(13, 54, 69, 0.6);
  }
  .rodal-dialog {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 800px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;

    // maybe we need some extra styling here
    // ...

    p {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 980px) {
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: auto 20px;
      padding: 40px 20px;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 24px;
      p {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    }
    .rodal-close {
      display: none;
    }
    .button-close {
      display: block;
      border: 2px solid #2A7DDF;
      color: #2A7DDF;
      width: 250px;
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 56px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see on the `JS` file below, I'm using the `NPM` module: `Rodal` to get the `Modal` window:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rodal-issue?file=src%2FModalWindow%2FModalWindow.js

**My problem is** that the rendering is not correct (I'm interested on `Firefox` and `Chrome`) because the modal window doesn't fit to the content:

[image]

Any idea on how to make `Rodal` to fit whatever variable content (dynamic size)?

If you know some approach for this, you can fork the `StackBlitz` project above and paste the link on your response.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Rodal has a prop - *customStyles* that expects an object. You will then pass an object of styles to it and that should solve your problem.
The style you want is *overflow-y:scroll* Example below:

```
<Rodal
        visible={someStateVariable}
        ... other props 
        
        customStyles={{ overflowY: 'scroll' }}
      >
{children}
</Rodal>
```